# Getters and Setters / Accessing variables from other classes

Tags: java

I have two classes Player and menuState, depending on a variable in the player class named "model" the model of the player  changes. Now I want to change the model via a button in the menu but I cant figure out how to acces the "model" variable from the menuState without creating a new Player object.

My Player class:

```
    package entitys;

    import State.State;
    import data.Handler;
    import grafik.Animation;
    import grafik.Assets;


    import java.awt.*;

    public class Player extends Creature {

    private Animation playerWalkLeft;
    private Animation playerWalkRight;
    private Animation playerIdle;
    private int model = 1;
    public Player(Handler handler, float x, float y) {
        super(handler, x, y, Creature.DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH, 112);

        bounds.x = 6;
        bounds.y = 52;
        bounds.width = 52;
        bounds.height = 64;


        if (model == 1) {
            playerWalkLeft = new Animation(6,Assets.fairy_run[0],Assets.fairy_run[1],Assets.fairy_run[2],Assets.fairy_run[3]);
            playerWalkRight = new Animation(6,Assets.fairy_run[0],Assets.fairy_run[1],Assets.fairy_run[2],Assets.fairy_run[3]);
            playerIdle = new Animation(10,Assets.fairy_idle[0],Assets.fairy_idle[1],Assets.fairy_idle[2],Assets.fairy_idle[3]);
        }else if (model == 2) {
            playerWalkLeft = new Animation(6, Assets.dragon_run[0], Assets.dragon_run[1], Assets.dragon_run[2], Assets.dragon_run[3]);
            playerWalkRight = new Animation(6, Assets.dragon_run[0], Assets.dragon_run[1], Assets.dragon_run[2], Assets.dragon_run[3]);
            playerIdle = new Animation(10, Assets.dragon_idle[0], Assets.dragon_idle[1], Assets.dragon_idle[2], Assets.dragon_idle[3]);
        }else if (model == 3) {
            playerWalkLeft = new Animation(6, Assets.wizzard_run[0], Assets.wizzard_run[1], Assets.wizzard_run[2], Assets.wizzard_run[3]);
            playerWalkRight = new Animation(6, Assets.wizzard_run[0], Assets.wizzard_run[1], Assets.wizzard_run[2], Assets.wizzard_run[3]);
            playerIdle = new Animation(10, Assets.wizzard_idle[0], Assets.wizzard_idle[1], Assets.wizzard_idle[2], Assets.wizzard_idle[3]);
        } else if (model == 4){
            playerWalkLeft = new Animation(6, Assets.knight_run[0], Assets.knight_run[1], Assets.knight_run[2], Assets.knight_run[3]);
            playerWalkRight = new Animation(6, Assets.knight_run[0], Assets.knight_run[1], Assets.knight_run[2], Assets.knight_run[3]);
            playerIdle = new Animation(10, Assets.knight_idle[0], Assets.knight_idle[1], Assets.knight_idle[2], Assets.knight_idle[3]);
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void tick() {
        getInput();
        move();

        handler.getCamera().centerOnEntity(this);
        playerWalkRight.runAnimation();
        playerIdle.runAnimation();
        playerWalkLeft.runAnimation();
    }

    private void getInput() {
        xMove = 0;
        yMove = 0;

        if (handler.getKeyManager().up)
            yMove = -speed;
        if (handler.getKeyManager().down)
            yMove = speed;
        if (handler.getKeyManager().left)
            xMove = -speed;
        if (handler.getKeyManager().right)
            xMove = speed;
        if (handler.getKeyManager().escape)
            State.setState(handler.getGame().menuState);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        if(xMove >0) {
            playerWalkRight.drawAnimation(g,(int) (x - handler.getCamera().getxOffset()), (int) (y - handler.getCamera().getyOffset()), width, 112);
        }
        else if(xMove<0){
            playerWalkLeft.drawAnimation(g,(int) (x - handler.getCamera().getxOffset()), (int) (y - handler.getCamera().getyOffset()), width, 112);

        }
        else {
            playerIdle.drawAnimation(g,(int) (x - handler.getCamera().getxOffset()), (int) (y - handler.getCamera().getyOffset()), width, 112);

        }
        if (handler.getKeyManager().debug) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawRect((int) (x + bounds.x - handler.getCamera().getxOffset()),
                    (int) (y + bounds.y - handler.getCamera().getyOffset()),
                    bounds.width, bounds.height);
        }
    }

    public int getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(int model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

My menuState class:

```
    package State;

    import data.Handler;
    import grafik.Assets;
    import ui.ClickListener;
    import ui.UIImageButton;
    import ui.UIManager;
    import entitys.Player;

    import java.awt.*;

    public class MenuState extends State {

    private UIManager uiManager;

    public MenuState(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
        uiManager = new UIManager(handler);
        handler.getMouseManager().setUiManager(uiManager);



        uiManager.addObject(new UIImageButton(144, 286, 64, 128, Assets.btn_dragon, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(){
            State.setState(handler.getGame().gameState);
            //p.setModel(2);
        }
        }));

        uiManager.addObject(new UIImageButton(464, 286, 64, 128, Assets.btn_wizzard, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(){
                State.setState(handler.getGame().gameState);
                //p.setModel(3);
            }
        }));

        uiManager.addObject(new UIImageButton(784, 286, 64, 128, Assets.btn_knight, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(){
                State.setState(handler.getGame().gameState);
                //p.setModel(4);
            }
        }));
        uiManager.addObject(new UIImageButton(1104, 286, 64, 128, Assets.btn_fairy, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(){
                State.setState(handler.getGame().gameState);
                //p.setModel(1);

            }
        }));


    }


    @Override
    public void tick() {
        uiManager.tick();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        uiManager.render(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: `model` is a field of the Player class, so yes, you need an instance of the Player class to operate upon.

Comment: after you've created the `Player` instance you can access the model value via `getModel()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the model field in the MenuState class and change its value on click, instead of model field in Player class if you don't want it linked to a specific player instance, that is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the model Integer is not bound to a specific player object, then just change it into a static variable. If not, you need the Player Object by creating it or saving it in something like a Map.